# Understanding rewriting finite summations

Tags: summation

I'm trying to rapidly work through an online course on probability theory, and have come across an issue with rewriting summations where my answers don't agree with the course's. I remember finding rewriting summations somewhat elusive when I learned about it, so I just want to make sure I'm not doing something obviously wrong.

The goal is to evaluate the sum:

$$\sum_{k=a+1}^b \frac{b-k+1}{b-a+1}$$

With $b \geq a \geq 0$ integers. From what I remember, I can set $k'= k-a$ and write this as:

$$\sum_{k'=1}^{b-a} \frac{b-(k'+a)+1}{b-a+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{b-a} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{b-a+1} \right)= (b-a) - \frac{1}{b-a+1} \sum_{k=1}^{b-a} k$$

The exercise solutions, however, instead end up with:

$$\frac{1}{b-a+1} \sum_{k=1}^{b-a} k$$

Actually, now that I'm writing this, I notice that since:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{b-a} k = \frac{(b-a+1)(b-a)}{2}$$

Both expressions are actually the same, but the solutions haven't used that fact yet at this point. I now wonder how to rewrite the original sum to get their answer, as it seems simpler.

Comment: Set $k' = b - k + 1$

Comment: Well now I just feel silly for not realising I can do that and simply flip the summation.